# Android: using LayoutInflater.inflate to pass custom parameters to a constructor

Tags: android, custom-component, layout-inflater

This has been bothering me for a while, and none of my searching has yielded results. If I have a custom GUI element, I can use a LayoutInflater to inflate it as I would a normal component. The inflation call results in a call to my custom GUI element's constructor, and all is well.

However, what if I want to add a custom parameter to my element's constructor? Is there a way I can pass this parameter in using LayoutInflater?

For example:

In main xml, I have a holder for my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/myFrameLayoutHolder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

and a MyFrameLayout.xml file:

```
 <com.example.MyFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/MyFLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1 >
    <!-- Cool custom stuff -->
 </com.example.MyFrameLayout>
```

and an inflater call:

```
LayoutInflater MyInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout myFLayoutHolder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myFrameLayoutHolder);

MyFrameLayout L = ((MyFrameLayout) MyInflater.inflate(R.layout.MyFLayout, myFLayoutHolder, false));
myFLayoutHolder.addView(L);
```

If, in my class that extends FrameLayout, I add a parameter to my constructor, I get a crash:

```
public class MyFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private int myInt;

    public MyFrameLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MyFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0, 0);
    }

    public MyFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, int myParameter) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        myInt = myParameter;
        //Amazing feats of initialization
    }
}
```

Now, it's easy enough to work around this issue by defining a custom init method that I call right after layout inflation, but that seems clumsy to me. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You cant define a constructor with your own parameter because your constructor signature conflicts with FrameLayout's own constructor signature and you are not calling `super(context, attrs, defStyle);`, instead you are calling `super(context, attrs);` which is incomplete for this constructor.

You must need to define all three native constructors exactly as they are:

```
FrameLayout(Context context)
FrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
FrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
```

What you can do is to use your own (custom) attributes in xml and then retrieve them in your MyFrameLayout's **attrs** object

Comment: Woops, I was trying to make my code as simple as possible to illustrate my point, and neglected to include the overloaded constructors. I've edited my question. 

Could you elaborate on your last sentence?

Comment: regarding my last sentence, read this: http://kevindion.com/2011/01/custom-xml-attributes-for-android-widgets/

Comment: and this http://staticallytyped.wordpress.com/2011/04/16/android-custom-xml-attributes-and-views/

Answer (score 0):

If the custom component is inflate by XML file or inflate method. You dont´t pass elemnts in the construct because this is not support in android.